# Memory management issue about Swift for-loop

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I take over some legacy code, and there's a code snippet like this

```
let albumGroups = data.getJSONArray("groups")
let groupNum = albumGroups.length()
var album: JSONObject

for i in 0..<groupNum
{
    album = albumGroups.getJSONObject(i)
    orderSummary.album.name[i] = album.getString("name")
}
```

It runs without any issue when the app is built in Debug mode.
But if it is built in Release mode, it crashes at `album.getString("name")` when i is 1. The error shows that the album variable was deallocated.

I tried running the app with Address Sanitizer flag enabled.

[image: Address Sanitizer debug]

[image]

My question is, as far as I know, the album variable is out of the loop's scope, why it was deallocated after the first loop ended?

Answer (score 0):

Check that `orderSummary.album` isn't a weak reference. If it is, the `Album` you initialize on line 1 is destroyed immediately, which would explain the crash when you attempt to set `orderSummary.album.name[i]`.

Comment: That line of code may be misleading, I've deleted it.